# Merge objects of a linear array with objects of a nested array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays A and B that contain objects. A is my pre-existing array and B is the array I'm using to mutate A.

Here are my requirements for merging B into A:

If a member of B exists in A, I need to replace the A object in place with the B object but retain all of the properties from the A object, overwriting any matching properties with the properties of the B object.

If a B member does not exist in A, I need to add it to the array so that it becomes a sibling of the first object in A.

Here are my two arrays, A and B:

```
let a = [
  {
    "key": "parent-1",
    "type": "parent",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "parent-1-1",
        "type": "parent",
        "items": [
          {
              "key": "child-1-1",
              "dataType": "text",
              "description": "foo",
              "someproperty": "stays"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "parent-1-2",
        "type": "parent",
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "child-1-2",
            "dataType": "text"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]   
  }
]

let b = [
  {
      "key": "child-1-1",
      "dataType": "text",
      "description": "bar"
  },
  {
      "key": "child-2",
      "dataType": "text",
      "description": "Since this does not appear in A it should be inserted as a next sibling to first array element (parent-1)"
  }
]
```

and here is my current method to merge the arrays:

```
const c = [
  ...a.filter(i => !b.some(j => j.key===i.key)),
  ...b.map(i => ({...a.find(j => j.key===i.key) ?? {}, ...i}))
]
console.log(c)
```

The issue I have is that my method above only works for linear objects and breaks down when objects have children. I need to modify my approach to work with complex objects. I'm looking for suggestions on would be a better approach.

Here is the expected result I'm trying to achieve:

```
c = [
    {
    "key": "parent-1",
    "type": "parent",
    "items": [
        {
        "key": "parent-1-1",
        "type": "parent",
        "items": [
            {
                "key": "child-1-1",
                "dataType": "text",
                "description": "bar",
                "someproperty": "stays"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "key": "parent-1-2",
        "type": "parent",
        "items": [
            {
            "key": "child-1-2",
            "dataType": "text"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]   
    },
    {
        "key": "child-2",
        "dataType": "text",
        "description": "Since this does not appear in A it goes as sibling to  first el: parent-1"
    }
]
```

Comment: I guess that you need some kind of recursion. :melting-face:
Combine complex objects that contain children, you can use a recursive approach that iterates through all properties of each object and combines them recursively.

Comment: @LubošHájek, I suppose since filter and find only work on arrays, they see the nested objects as a single value and the filter does not reach into the object beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fancy method, but a classic recursion should work:

```js
let a = [{
  "key": "parent-1",
  "type": "parent",
  "items": [{
      "key": "parent-1-1",
      "type": "parent",
      "items": [{
        "key": "child-1-1",
        "dataType": "text",
        "description": "foo",
        "someproperty": "stays"
      }]
    },
    {
      "key": "parent-1-2",
      "type": "parent",
      "items": [{
        "key": "child-1-2",
        "dataType": "text"
      }]
    }
  ]
}]

let b = [{
    "key": "child-1-1",
    "dataType": "text",
    "description": "bar"
  },
  {
    "key": "child-2",
    "dataType": "text",
    "description": "Since this does not appear in A it should be inserted as a next sibling to first array element (parent-1)"
  }
]

function traverse(arr, bElm) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return false
  }

  let isFound = false

  arr.forEach((arrElm, idx, originalArray) => {
    if (arrElm.key === bElm.key) {
      originalArray[idx] = {
        ...originalArray[idx],
        ...bElm,
      }

      isFound = true
    }

    if ('items' in arrElm) {
      let result = traverse(arrElm.items, bElm)

      isFound = result || isFound
    }
  })

  return isFound
}

b.forEach(bElm => {
  let result = traverse(a, bElm)

  if (!result) {
    a.push(bElm)
  }
})

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help. I just got my head above water to check here. Been crazy busy on another project. I'll check your approach as soon as I get a minute!